# Unable to load grid with searched records in EXTJS4

Tags: forms, grid, extjs4

I have a formpanel with a form of 5 fields(used for 'search') and a grid with a few columns(grid and form are binded).

Initially, I want to load grid with all records (json data)and it has been done.
And the issue is when I click on 'search' button (not using any parameters), my PHP script is returning the correct json format but it is not loaded in to the grid(Grid still have all records).

I have been trying on these since 3days but unable to solve this. I'm new to EXTJS4. Please help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: On your 'Search' button click event, assuming you fetch your data from your PHP script in that event, you can use your stores *load*, *loadData*, or *loadRawData* see methods http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want but take a look at this grid search example http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/live-search-grid.html